# Modify connectionString in WCF Data Services 5.6

Tags: c#, wpf, oracle, odata, wcf-data-services

I'm using Oracle DataAccess (the last one), I have many Database users inside it. So, I want to create the connectionString in my client application (WPF) and pass it to the server. I'm doing the following in my server:

```
protected override POSContext CreateDataSource()
{
    HttpRequest req = HttpContext.Current.Request;

    if (req.Headers != null && Array.FindIndex(req.Headers.AllKeys, c=>c.Equals("db", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) > 0)
    {
        string database = req.Headers["db"]; 
        string user = req.Headers["user"];
        string pass = req.Headers["pass"];

        StringBuilder conexion = new StringBuilder();
        conexion.Append("DATA SOURCE=");
        conexion.Append(database);
        conexion.Append(";USER ID=");
        conexion.Append(user);
        conexion.Append(";PASSWORD=");
        conexion.Append(pass);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(conexion.ToString()))
            return new POSContext(conexion.ToString());
    }

    return null;//new POSContext();
}
```

In the client, I have the following code:

```
var context = new POS.DataServices.POSContext(new Uri(Storage.Current.UrlService)); // Something like this http://localhost/POService.svc
context.BuildingRequest += (s, args) => //Or SendingRequest2 produces the same result
{
    args.Headers.Add("db", Storage.Current.Configuraciones.DB);
    args.Headers.Add("user", Storage.Current.Configuraciones.UserName);
    args.Headers.Add("pass", Storage.Current.Configuraciones.Password);
};

MessageBox.Show(proxy.POS_CIUDAD.ToList().FirstOrDefault().CIU_DESC); //Alert the city name
```

When I debug my application I have an error (request error). My client code is trying to Show the message first and then go to the BuildingRequest. How can I pass the connectionString before Entity calls?

Comment: Anyone? Is it impossible to do that with Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

CreateDataSource is called once when the service starts, that's why you get the error there.

I think you can try the following:

1. Add a connection string a property on POSContext, and give POSContext a parameterless constructor. That is the connection string could be set later. And maybe you need to make sure the connection is only set when the connection string is ready.
2. Override OnStartProcessingRequest method, and change the connection string on CurrentDataSource (POSContext class)